# Web Scraping: Page exists but getting 404 using requests/urllib

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the following page:
http://usbcdirectory.com/listing/1-us-black-chambers

I am using Python 3.5.0

Here is my code:

```py
urllib.request.urlopen('http://usbcdirectory.com/listing/1-us-black-chambers')
```

Using the above I am getting a 404 not found error. However, the page exists when I open it from the browser.

I tried searching solution to this problem and here is what I have found:

1. Change urllib to requests: I already did this and got a 404 error in the status code

```
>>>requests.get('http://usbcdirectory.com/listing/1-us-black-chambers')
    
Request <404>
```

2. I checked my link which is correct
3. I tried to find out if the page is generated using JavaScript. I believe it is not.

What is the issue with the web page here? Are they blocking scraping in some way or it is an issue with the URL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you guessed, they are probably blocking your request. You can pass custom headers to simulate your request more like a request from a real browser:

```
import requests

url = 'http://usbcdirectory.com/listing/1-us-black-chambers'
headers = {'Accept': 'text/html'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: @ Ritiek, your provided solution works. it's a nice finding. +1 for this. Btw, could you tell me why it didn't work `headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}`? Usually this is what we do to simulate a browser while passing a header like this. However, it didn't work out but your one did successfully.

Comment: @Topto It usually depends on the website on what kind of network requests they want to block. You can use [mitmproxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy) to intercept what all headers are being passed by your browser and replicate them in your code until it just works.

Comment: @Ritiek, Thank you very much. Your suggested solution worked.

Comment: @MayankMittal Please accept this answer if it works.

Comment: @SIM I found if I set User-Agent to "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36" worked nicely for me.

Answer (score 0):

It happend for me the same. thanks for sharing the solution. I also tried to use my personal User-Agent code and it worked. I used this code:

```
import requests

url = 'http://usbcdirectory.com/listing/1-us-black-chambers'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'your user agent'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
```