# requests.get(..) on uber eats always returns 404

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have been trying to learn some web scraping, so I thought let me build a webscraper to scrape latest offers from restaurants uber eats near me. However, I am stuck at the first step. Using requests always returns 404 error

```
requests.get("https://www.ubereats.com/", headers={'content-type':'text', 'User-Agent': 'Custom'})
```

I also tried using this script which I found somewhere(have closed that tab, will post the link if required)

```
import mechanize
import cookielib

# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

# debugging messages
#br.set_debug_http(True)
#br.set_debug_redirects(True)
#br.set_debug_responses(True)

# User-Agent
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

r = br.open('https://www.ubereats.com')
html = r.read()
```

The above script throws a "httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 404: Not Found" error.

I checked the robots.txt of ubereats and it seems they do allow scrapers

User-agent: *
Disallow:
Disallow: */search/?
Disallow: */delivery-details/
....

Kindly help me out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web Scraping: Page exists but getting 404 using requests/urllib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46843293/web-scraping-page-exists-but-getting-404-using-requests-urllib)

Comment: Also, it seems like the site for India is: `https://ubereats.com/en-IN/`

Comment: @AjayDabas: Adding 'Accept': 'text/html' was helpful. I was able to scrape the data for the webpage. However, how do I get the data for a particular location?

Comment: What do you mean by particular location?

Comment: My current location, which is Bangalore